# Is possible to change the points in a plot by numbers in GNUPLOT?

Tags: gnuplot

i would like to know if there is some way for customize the point symbols in a plot generated in gnuplot? I want to change the symbols in a plot by numbers, for example, change all '+' symbol by the number '1'.

Every help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just use pt '1' as long as you are plotting with points. For example, try:

```
plot sin(x) with points pt '1'
```

Comment: I forget to say that i'm plotting using the pdfcairo terminal. Respect you answer, I tried but is not working, neither by using 'x11' terminal

Comment: Hmmm. I just tried the x11 terminal and it works there. Are you upgraded to gnuplot 5?

Comment: It's working, so many thanks. Another question, the syntax used in the older versions to change the point's color it's no working when i use the number instead the usual characters. There is another way to change the points color?

by the way, thanks by the hint

Comment: You can use `plot sin(x) with points pt '1' textcolor rgb "red"`. Take a look at `help textcolor`.